# What is a failsafe way to embed Oracle12c database with a product?

Tags: oracle-12c

We are planning to embed Oracle12c as the default data source
for our application. That means, Oracle12c and our application
are going to reside on the same server.

Our application runs on 64-bit Windows and Linux platforms. So
far, from an installation perspective, we have two choices:

choice-1: We perform a silent installation of Oracle12c database
during our product installation followed by user account creation,
table creation for our application.

choice-2: We install Oracle12c server software alone in our in-house
64-bit windows, linux servers. Then we zip up our ORACLE_HOME and 
perform a clone of the oracle database in production followed by a 
silent run of database configuration assistant to create the database.

I would typically select choice-2 since it is less time consuming and
easier than a full installation everytime. But, I have the following
questions with regard to this :

1. If I choose the clone approach, is it necessary that my source and
   destination servers have the same machine architecture. For example, if
   I install Oracle12c server software alone in a 64-bit windows 2008 server VM, 
   will I be able to clone this source ORACLE_HOME to any 64-bit windows server
   irrespective of the underlying processing architecture ? (like Intel,AMD or any 
   bare metal physical server).
2. Which is a recommended approach from a fail-safe perspective ? (I know it is
   subjective ; nevertheless)

[N.B] The idea is to use a single instance non-CDB, so no plug gable databases